# Save changes to a database in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update the status of a user using Entity Framework 6 database first database, in MVC 5, where they are either active or inactive, but the changed status does not update in the database.

However, when I close the program and debug again the status has updated in the view and the database.

Why could this happening this way and how could it be solved?

database update code:

```
public void StatusChange(string userName)
{
    string currentStatus = amadeusUser.getUserStatus(userName);
    int userID = amadeusUser.getUserID(userName);
    if (currentStatus == "Active")
    {
        SaveStatus(1360, userID, userName);
    }
        else if (currentStatus == "Inactive")
    {
        SaveStatus(193, userID, userName);
    }
    }

private void SaveStatus(int status, int userID, string userName)
{        
    try
    {
        var rowChanger = amadeus.AmadeusUsers.Find(userID);
        rowChanger.Status = status;
        amadeus.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Controller:

```
//The controller calls a interface that calles the correct database's class
public ActionResult ChangeStatus(string userName, string applicationName)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Application.Applications, IRole> entry in Application.RoleMap)
    {
        if (entry.Key.ToString() == applicationName)
        {
            IRole role = entry.Value;
            role.StatusChange(userName);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("UserDetails", new { userName = userName });
}
```

Calls the following method:

```
//The controller calls a interface that calles the correct database's class
public ActionResult UserDetails(string userName)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> statuses = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<Application.Applications, IUser> entry in Application.UserMap)
    {
            IUser user = entry.Value;
            statuses.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), user.getUserStatus(userName));
    }
    ViewBag.ApplicationStatuses = statuses;
    ViewBag.UserName = userName;

    return View();
}
```

The dictionary only holds the database names and that works perfectly, if you need the code I can find it.

**Edit 2**

The View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Details";
}

<h2>User Details</h2>

<p><b>@ViewBag.UserName</b></p>

<table class="table">
     <tr>
         <th>
             Application Name
         </th>
        <th>
           Status
        </th>
         <th>

         </th>

    </tr>

        @if (ViewBag.ApplicationStatuses.Count > 0)
        {
            @*Iterating Amadeus model using ViewBag *@
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.ApplicationStatuses)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Key
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Value
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Change Status", "ChangeStatus", "User", new { userName = ViewBag.userName, applicationName = item.Key }, new { @class = "enableDisable" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("View Permissions", "Roles", new { userID = ViewBag.UserName, applicationName = item.Key })*
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you saying the program is reflecting the changes but you don't see them when examining the database?

Comment: amadeus.SaveChanges() is saving to the database, please explain a bit more of what you mean by "I have got the code to make the correct changes but not to save to the database." So you SaveChanges() is not working?

Comment: Basically the code functions but the database itself doesn't register any changes until the application is completely closed and restarted. @Missioninno Sorry meant to delete that line.

Comment: if ( amadeus.SaveChanges() > 0 ) { ... } try and see if it returns any value ?

Comment: what is amadeusUser - Entity or Context?

Comment: @Slippery Have you tried refreshing the database after saving instead of closing and opening the application? Does it have any changes?

Comment: @AndrewCounts neither the application or the database register the changes until the application has been closed and restarted.

Comment: @codebased amadeusUser would be the Entity.

Comment: @Missioninno no I haven't how would you refresh?

Comment: Ok, why don't you try with context.SaveChanges(..); ortherwise try with AcceptAllChanges(..) since I don' thave a full code it is hard to justify what would be causing this.

Comment: @Slippery I suspect this has something to do with refreshing the view, try refresh the view after saving and see if it updates to the view? and if it did, look for a solution to refresh the view after saving. I need to look at your controller and view to see what is going on.

Comment: @Missioninno I have added the controllers, though refreshing the view works elsewhere in the program. I checked to see what was in the database field after calling save database and it showed the incorrect value.

Comment: @slippery Sorry I have no idea where the problem is, never actually  tried to do it your way. I am not sure if its "incorrect value" or "correct value but not refreshing" in the database.

Comment: @Missioninno the value is correct, is there another way to solve the problem? anything that allows the application to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar error, You should use a using statement to wrap your database context.

To clarify try:

```
using(dbEntity amadeus = new dbEntities())
{
    if (entry.Key.ToString() == applicationName)
    {
        IRole role = entry.Value;
        role.StatusChange(userName);
    }
}
```